# Print factor summary in "transposed" way

Tags: r, printing, transpose, summary, r-factor

I have a factor variable and I want to retrieve a count of each level. This is easy with `summary()` function:

```
> h <- rnorm(100, 170, 10)
> hf <- cut(h, breaks=10)
> summary(hf)
(142,147] (147,153] (153,158] (158,163] (163,169] (169,174] (174,180] (180,185] (185,190] 
        5         3         7        20        11        23        12        11         6 
(190,196] 
        2
```

But I want this to be included in knitr report, so I would prefer a more human-friendly way of displaying data. The most obvious way is transposing it, so I get something like this:

```
(142,147]           5
(147,153]           3
(153,158]           7
(158,163]          20
(163,169]          11
(169,174]          23
(174,180]          12
(180,185]          11
(185,190]           6
(190,196]           2
```

The question is: **what is the best way to achieve this?**
(And by "the best" I mean "clean, efficient, compact and without any side effects")

Below I outline few ways I have tried and why I am not perfectly happy with any of these

#### as.data.frame

```
> r <- as.data.frame(summary(hf))
> colnames(r) <- ""
> r

(142,147]  5
(147,153]  3
(153,158]  7
(158,163] 20
(163,169] 11
(169,174] 23
(174,180] 12
(180,185] 11
(185,190]  6
(190,196]  2
```

I don't like the fact that I use temporary variable to store data frame and one line of code just to suppress second column header (which reads `summary(hf)` by default, and is not very helpful). If I could hide column name while converting summary to data.frame, or by using some printing function/argument, that would be perfect.

#### table

```
> as.data.frame(table(hf))
          hf Freq
1  (142,147]    5
2  (147,153]    3
3  (153,158]    7
4  (158,163]   20
5  (163,169]   11
6  (169,174]   23
7  (174,180]   12
8  (180,185]   11
9  (185,190]    6
10 (190,196]    2
```

Here headers are more readable, but now I have unneeded row names. Which leads me to next solution.

#### write.table

```
> write.table(as.data.frame(table(hf)), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
"(142,147]" 5
"(147,153]" 3
"(153,158]" 7
"(158,163]" 20
"(163,169]" 11
"(169,174]" 23
"(174,180]" 12
"(180,185]" 11
"(185,190]" 6
"(190,196]" 2
```

This is fine as long as factor level names has the same length. When they have different length, things start to be misaligned:

```
> write.table(as.data.frame(table(h>170)), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
"FALSE" 51
"TRUE" 49
```

If anyone has read so far, let me repeat my question:
What is the best way to get number of occurrences of each factor level displayed in "transposed" table, possibly without any side-effects?

Comment: Not an answer, but `cbind(summary(hf))` also works nicely. Take a look.

Comment: @RichardScriven That's the same as `as.matrix(summary(hf))`.

Comment: Would `setNames(as.data.frame(summary(hf)), "")` be okay?

Comment: I think your data.frame method is user friendly; just assign a name: `data.frame(N=summary(hf))`

Comment: @Roland: yes, that would be OK. Actually, this is all I needed to make my first proposal "perfect". I didn't know `setNames` function before. Can you post this as answer, so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you simply want this:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(summary(hf)), "")
```

Of course you could also wrap your code in a function ...